# Sorting sprites and Line Renderer in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

I am developing a mobile app with Unity and have many image objects, as well as a panel and a line renderer. But I just can't get things to render in the right order! Now I have created a sample project for this purpose and screenshotted it. I would be glad if someone could help me.

I would like the things to be rendered in the following order:

1. the background.
2. the line should then be drawn on the background.
3. the nodes should be displayed above the line.
4. then the panel is placed on top and covers everything else.

Currently, the line is displayed above everything else. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you change the order in layer, it might make it so it will be behind the nodes. Also, you could try dragging the line renderer between the nodes and the background.